# pass Application as argument in WPF

Tags: wpf, casting

i have a solution combined with several projects.
this is my App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
     private SiteManager _siteManager = new SiteManager();

    public SiteManager SiteManager
    {
        get { return _siteManager; }
        set { _siteManager = value; }
    }
}
```

during my run i call another project in the same solution

```
SiteDll.MainWindow siteManagerDialog = new SiteDll.MainWindow();
siteManagerDialog.Show();
```

but i dont know how to pass all vars in App.xaml.cs to SiteDll.MainWindow siteManagerDialog.

i tried:

```
SiteDll.MainWindow siteManagerDialog = new SiteDll.MainWindow((App)Application.Current);
siteManagerDialog.Show();
```

and cast it in SiteDll.MainWindow constructor:

```
public MainWindow(object me)
{
    Application app = ((App)me);
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

but i get casting error...
what is the correct way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You are casting YourApplication1.App type to YourApplication2.App which are different types. That's why you get a invalid cast exception.

What you can do is, you can put your common variables in a separate assembly and reference this assembly from both of your applications.

---

Edit
I would also suggest you to add a 'WPF User Control Library' and then reference it when you are using wpf windows/pages/user controls from other assemblies, to prevent such confusions.